# issue with image rotation on android devices

Tags: android, camera, rotation, android-camera

I created a custom camera activity in my Android app but am having issues with images being rotated 90 degrees based on which device it's taken on.  This only happens on particular devices and I can't seem to figure out why.

What I do in the app is

1. Update the variable "mOrientation" which saves the current orientation of the phone in degrees (0-360)
2. When the user taps the shutter button, I check what the last saved orientation was and rotate the image accordingly before saving it.

I've tested on two different devices, a Huawei phone and a Samsung Galaxy S II.  What I'm finding is that while I'm able to determine that the orientation of the phone is being updated correctly and that both have a default portrait orientation, they require different "mOrientation" values, offset by 90 degrees, in order to be oriented correctly when saved.

Here's how I check the current orientation:

```
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
if(cameraPreview.getDeviceDefaultOrientation() == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    if (orientation >= 315 || orientation < 45) {
         if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL) {                          
        mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL;
          }
}else if (orientation < 315 && orientation >= 225) {
          if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL) {
        mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL;
           }                       
    }else if (orientation < 225 && orientation >= 135) {
          if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED) {
        mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED;
           }                       
    }else { // orientation <135 && orientation > 45
        if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED) {
        mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED;
        }                       
    }   
}else{
   if (orientation >= 315 || orientation < 45) {
      if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL) {
           mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL;
       } 
    }else if (orientation < 315 && orientation >= 225) {
       if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED) {
        mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED;
        }                                                  
    }else if (orientation < 225 && orientation >= 135) {
        if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED) {                                          
           mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED;           
         }                                                
    }else { // orientation <135 && orientation > 45
        if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL) {                          
        mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL;
    }
  }
}
```

And here's how I save the image:

```
private PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera cam) {
        Log.d(TAG, "saving picture");
        Log.d(TAG, "portrait image? " + Boolean.toString(cameraPreview.getDeviceDefaultOrientation() == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT));
        Log.d(TAG, "mOrientaiton: " + mOrientation);

        //Degrees to rotate image by when saving
        int degree = 0;

        // do not rotate image, just put rotation info in
        if(cameraPreview.getDeviceDefaultOrientation() == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            switch (mOrientation) {
            case ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED:
                Log.d(TAG, "orientation landscape inverted");
                degree = 90;
                break;
            case ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL:
                Log.d(TAG, "orientation portrait normal");
                degree = 0;
                break;
            case ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL:
                Log.d(TAG, "orientation landscape normal");
                degree = 270;
                break;
            case ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED:
                Log.d(TAG, "orientation portrait inverted");
                degree = 180;
                break;
            }
        }else{
            switch (mOrientation) {
            case ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED:
                degree = 270;
                break;
            case ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL:
                degree = 180;
                break;
            case ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL:
                degree = 0;
                break;
            case ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED:
                degree = 90;
                break;
            }
        }

        Bitmap bMap;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 6;
        options.inDither = false; // Disable Dithering mode
        options.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to gc that whether it needs free
        // memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
        options.inInputShareable = true; // Which kind of reference will be
        // used to recover the Bitmap
        // data after being clear, when
        // it will be used in the future
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[32 * 1024];
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
        if(degree != 0){
            bMap = rotate(bMap, degree);
        }

        //Getting the picture's unique file to be added to the folder
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        /*
         * This catches errors when creating the output file to put the picture in
         */
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Error creating media file, check storage permissions");

            //After the camera has finished taking the picture
            handler.post(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Remove white border from preview
                    Log.d(TAG, "removing white background from preview");
                    cameraPreview.setBackgroundResource(0);                 
                }

            });
            //Setting the onclicklistener back on the shutter
            shutter.setOnClickListener(shutterClickListener);

            //Restarting the preview as soon as picture is done
            camera.startPreview();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error saving file. Try restarting the camera.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return;
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            //Saving the image
            out = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            bMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            if (bMap != null) {
                bMap.recycle();
                bMap = null;
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                //Assuring we always close the output stream
                if(out!=null){
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        myHorizontalLayout.add(Uri.parse(pictureFile.getPath()));

          MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[] { Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) 
                  {
                      Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                      Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);

                      camera.startPreview();

                      if(myHorizontalLayout.getItemList().size() == 1){
                          //Have added the first item to the pictures set check to green
                          MenuItem check = menu.findItem(R.id.save);
                      }

                      //After the camera has finished taking the picture
                      handler.post(new Runnable(){
                          @Override
                          public void run() {
                              //Remove white border from preview
                              Log.d(TAG, "removing white background");
                              cameraPreview.setBackgroundResource(0);                 
                          }
                      });
                      //Setting the onclicklistener back on the shutter
                      shutter.setOnClickListener(shutterClickListener);
                  }
                });


    }
};
```

I would be really grateful if anyone could help me with this.  Also, if anyone has general advice on how to test camera configurations across Android devices without having to own many different makes of phones, I would appreciate that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> am having issues with images being rotated 90 degrees based on which device it's taken on

Your pictures are probably technically fine. Some devices do not rotate the image themselves, but instead set an EXIF header telling the image *viewer* to rotate the image. Not all image viewers do this.

> Also, if anyone has general advice on how to test camera configurations across Android devices without having to own many different makes of phones, I would appreciate that too.

Rely on [somebody else](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) to do that work for you. :-)

Comment: thanks for the help!  I ended up fixing the problem by just checking whether the device is a Huawei device and offsetting the image rotation based on that (I informally have seen the app working on other devices, and the Huawei device is the only one I've seen that has had issues).

Comment: @scientiffic: Oh, trust me, many more devices set EXIF headers rather than actually rotate the image.

Comment: is there some way for me to check this before I apply the rotation?

Comment: @scientiffic: You're welcome to check for the existence of the EXIF orientation header and take steps based upon that.

Comment: thanks for your help.  how do I retrieve exif orientation before the file is saved?  do you suggest saving the image and then applying the rotation afterward based on the exif orientation header?

Comment: @scientiffic: "how do I retrieve exif orientation before the file is saved?" -- I wound up grabbing a bunch of EXIF code out of the AOSP MMS app, which can get EXIF headers out of a `byte[]`. I would avoid saving the image first, as that will be slow.

Comment: @scientiffic : did you find a great solution for that? I have the same issue like you...